# How to embed Google Speech to Text API in Python program?

Tags: python, google-api, speech-recognition

I have a project in which I have created a chat program between a client and host, and I have to embed Speech to Text in it. Is there any way by which I can embed Google Speech to Text API in my program ??

Comment: Google does not offer a public API; so if you are concerned about your software, do not use an unofficial API that is not supported and is subject to change/cancellation by Google. If by embed you mean "offline", then no that is not possible.

Comment: No i mean online embedding..!

Answer (score 5):

There is a package in PyPI called [Speech Recognition](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SpeechRecognition/) which looks like it will do this. The live (i.e. via microphone) API looks fantastically simple.

```
# NOTE: this requires PyAudio because it uses the Microphone class
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:                # use the default microphone as the audio source
    audio = r.listen(source)                   # listen for the first phrase and extract it into audio data

try:
    print("You said " + r.recognize(audio))    # recognize speech using Google Speech Recognition
except LookupError:                            # speech is unintelligible
    print("Could not understand audio")
```

It also has capabilities for transcribing WAV files, running as a background process, providing confidence values for the transcription, etc.